# how to get stdClass Object $date value?

Tags: php

Crete Api using core PHP, i want to get **$date** value in a variable and convert it into **2021-12-07 10:22:32** date format

server response as below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [$date] => 2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700
)
```

i tried like below

```
$publishedDate = (!empty($rows->publishedDate)) ? $rows->publishedDate : "";
print_r($publishedDate->$date);
```

Comment: Hi Jack, what is the output of print_r($publishedDate->$date) ?

Comment: `$publishedDate->{'$date'}`

Comment: Thanks! @phil, got value of publishedDate.